# User signup system in Django with custom fields

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to make a user Signup system along with his profile.

my **models.py**:

```
class myCustomeUser(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique="True", blank=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(myCustomeUser, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField()
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/profile/")
```

my **forms.py**:

```
class SignUpForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
```

my **views.py**:

```
class index(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = SignUpForm
    template_name = 'index.html'
```

Now here my problem is, the form gives me an option to choose any user (with dropdown) to create a profile.... but I want to create a user also on that page (not pick an option from dropdown). How can I try for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your need to connect your user creation form with Django post_Save signals.

I will point out a tutorial that can assist you

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Answer (score 1):

Your signup form should use myCustomeUser

So that you create a user first

Then.with the help of "signals" you can create profiles automatically every time a user is created